# WP customizing view order admin popup

Tags: wordpress

IN WP 3.3 was [introduced](https://woocommerce.wordpress.com/2017/11/16/wc-3-3-order-screen-changes-including-a-new-preview-function-ready-for-feedback/) view order button, which is visible near order (arrow)

Where is possible find the template for this popup? Want make few changes, as ex - add PDF create button.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i customize it with css change, which make with enqueuing custom css file. Main problem was - set it wider. So i find where css for widering is. And add css portino:

```
add_action('admin_head', function (){

        wp_register_script($handle = "wooc-custom", $src =  get_template_directory_uri() . "/woocommerce/css/add_custom.css");
        wp_enqueue_style($handle, $src);
    },99);
```

Then in css file, inside theme woocommerce/css folder:

```
.wc-backbone-modal .wc-backbone-modal-content {min-width:700px;}
```